# Redmi 9a Android 11 to 10 Bricked

Tags: recovery-mode, fastboot, unbricking, redmi

A friend of mine has a Redmi 9a. He attempted to fastboot from version 11 to 10 to increase performance on on 2gb of RAM. He got to fastboot before attempting a flash of Android 10. When it claimed it was finished, he restarted after Flash Successful screen. It now no longer responds, but is picked up on his computer. He also tried spflash, but it gave these three error codes:

```
0xC0010001
0xC0070004
0xC0050005
```

It crashes immediately on start mostly with 0001 and 0005, and gets some way on 0004 before once again crashing.

Attached is the image of the phone. I can't see an obvious problem, but I am no phone expert, I mainly deal with PC hardware and low level code (C and the like).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
[image: image of phone]. [image: motherboard][image: motherboard other side]

Comment: The last time I know, there is a bootloader downgrade protection on some Android devices that will prevent flashing lower Android versions, not sure if this is the case or not...